# How to make Joomla search for Module Content

Tags: search, joomla, module

Most of my webpage content are currently being presented in various modules and I have blank articles. The default joomla search engine is unable to search any of my modules' content. Are there any plugins out there that will let me search for module content?

Thanks

Comment: I think the basic problem is not the search, but how are you going to render the results of the search? You can certainly easily make a search or finder plugin to do the search but the problem is that they need to return items and display them somehow. So you would also need to make a new front end layout that would load modules for the search results.  It's not necessarily that hard to do I guess, just thinking about it.

Answer (score 0):

There is no plugin that I know of.

You can easily create one. Follow the instructions at https://docs.joomla.org/J3.x:Creating_a_search_plugin and change the queries so that you look into the **content** field of the **#__modules** table.

Of course you still have one problem left. Once you have your modules listed in the search results, what are they linked to? I.e. what page will open when you click on one of those search results?

That is something you'll have to find a creative solution to :-)

Comment: Joomla search should search for content based on the URLs of the menu items regardless whether its articles or modules. Just like google or any other search engines; they search for content inside the body of the htmls from whichever urls that it indexed. Thats how joomla should search and return the result and its what user really want.

Comment: Pity, that's not the way Joomla works. You can complain to Joomla leadership. My answer still stands true.